# Change Shape Background Picture in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a picture to shape from the worksheet. I have an embedded picture by Name "MyPic" in a worksheet. I want to fill the shape with this picture. I tried the following codes.

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
         Set imgpath = Worksheets("Static").Shapes("MyPic") 'this is picture
        .visible = msoTrue
        '.UserPicture "C:\Users\ak\Desktop\settingsImg.jpg" 'working
        '.UserPicture = Worksheets("Static").Range("M2").value 'not working
         .UserPicture = imgpath 'not working
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
End with
```

my problem is similar to this thread https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-excel-change-shape-fill-to-existing-picture-from-another-sheet.927668/
Thanks

Comment: `.UserPicture` expects the path of a picture saved elsewhere, not an embedded picture.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the reply. you mean I need to save the picture before I can use it?

Comment: If you are using `.UserPicture`, then yes.

Comment: @BigBen any workaround to this?

Comment: @BigBen The reason to ask workaround is if I give the path of the image from the local system then it may not work in another system if the path is different or image is deleted.